# Python Tkinter: creating canvas inside function will cause memory leak?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a function that creates a new canvas every time it's called

```
def show_cities():
    height = 20
    lb.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
    
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=150, height=350)
    canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
        
    for i in cities_to_select:
        print(i)
        city = tk.Label(canvas, text=cities[i])
        city.place(x=10, y=height)
        height += 20;
    cities_to_select[:] = []
```

Will the canvas object be recreated with every function call or will it be just created along old one?
Will such code cause memory leak?

Comment: Try placing your disposable canvas in a `Toplevel` window then destroy it. There should be no change in memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Each time `show_cities` is called, a new canvas will be created. Since you aren't destroying the old canvas, then yes, this will create a small memory leak.